# How to separate the line which contain searched word from paragraph in golang

Tags: regex, go

I have a string of multiple line . I am looking for a method to show only that line which contain the searched word.

```
`testStr := "This is first line. This is second line. This is third line."
    word := "second"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(".*" + word + ".")
    testJson := re.FindStringSubmatch(testStr)
    fmt.Println(testJson[0])`
```

I am getting the result "This is first line. This is second" but I am expecting the  "This is second line."

Answer (score 3):

Use this regular expressionist:

```
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^.]*` + word + `[^.]*\.`)
```

The break down:

- match sequence without a full stop: `[^.]*`
- match the word
- match sequence without a full stop: `[^.]*`
- match full stop `\.`

https://go.dev/play/p/GCwG5Fup7QE